# substitution of ConfigurationManager

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I'm working on an windows phone 7 project, I want to read the appsettings from config file such as app.config using ConfigurationManager class, but seems it is not implemented in windows phone 7 sdk, I have no idea now how to resolve this issue, anyone knows this?

I'm using vs 2010
OS windows 7

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I once implemented a simple config class, that read configuration from a xml file added to the project. Take a look at https://github.com/igorkulman/Kulman.WP7/blob/master/Kulman.WP7/Config/AppConfig.cs.

This requires having app.config in the project and calling AppConfig.ParseAndLoadAppConfig() in App.xaml.cs constructor.